# Upsert an embedded array at specific position - will my work-around work in production?

Tags: mongodb

I'm storing timeseries in MongoDB and the strucuture is as follows:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5128e567df6232180e00fa7d"),
  "values" : [563.424, 520.231, 529.658, 540.459, 544.271, 512.641, 579.591, 613.878, 627.708, 636.239, 672.883, 658.895, 646.44, 619.644, 623.543, 600.527, 619.431, 596.184, 604.073, 596.556, 590.898, 559.334, 568.09, 568.563],
  "day" : 20110628,
}
```

The values-array is representing a value for each hour. So the position is important since position `0 = first hour`, `1 = second hour` and so on.

To update the value of a specific hour is quite easy. For example, to update the 7th hour of the day I do this:

```
db.timeseries.update({day:20130203},{$set : {values.6 : 482.65}}, {upsert : true})
```

My problem is that I would like to use **upsert**, like this

```
db.timeseries.update({day:20130203},{$set : {values.6 : 482.65}})
```

But if the document does not exist, MongoDB will craete an embedded document intead of an embedded array. Like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5128e567df6232180e00fa7d"),
  "values" : {"6" : 482.65},
  "day" : 20130203,
}
```

There is a ticket to add a feature to solve this issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2363?focusedCommentId=157076&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel), but meanwhile I have come up with a work-around to solve this in my case.

What I do, is that I first created a **uniqe-index on the day-field**. And whenever I want to upsert a hourly volume I do these two commands.

```
db.timeseries.insert({day:20130203, values : []}); // Will be rejected if it exists
db.timeseries.update({day:20130203},{$set : {values.6 : 482.65}});
```

The first statement tried to create a new document - and thanks to the uniqe-index the insert will be rejected if it already exists. If not, a document with an embedded array for value-field will be created. This ensures that the update will work.

Result:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5128e567df6232180e00fa7d"),
  "values" : [null,null,null,null,null,null,482.65],
  "day" : 20130203,
}
```

**And here's is my question**

In production, when several commands like this will be run simultaneously can I be sure that my update-command will be executed **after** my insert-command? *Note that I want to run both commands in unsafe-mode, that is I will not wait for any response from the server.*

(It would also be interesting to here comments about my work-around from a performance perspective.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally yes, there is a way to ensure that two requests from a client use the same connection. By using the same connection you force a strict order of execution on the server.

The way to accomplish this are different for different drivers.

For the [Asynchronous Java Driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/) you can create a "Serialized" MongoClient from the initial MongoClient instance and it will ensure that all requests use a single connection.

For the 10gen java [driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads) it will automatically (via a ThreadLocal) try to use the same connection.  You can also give a hint to the driver via the DB.requestStart()/DB.requestEnd() methods that a group of commands need to be pipe-lined.

The startRequest/endRequest applies to most of the 10gen drivers.  As another example the PyMongo driver mongo_client has a [start_request()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.4.2/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.start_request)/end_request() pair.

Comment: I'm using the PHP-driver. In my code I first create a connection (MongoClient) and then use that same connection for each command. So in my case I do force a strict order of execution, right?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  I am not a PHP expert but looking at the docs it appears that a single MongoClient is a single connection to the server.  It that is the case then yes, using the same MongoClient for the two command should force a strict order.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance point of view, it is better using only one access to the database than two. Cannot you use $push instead of $set for updating the values field?

Comment: No, then an object will be created - instead of an array (as shown in my 4th code example). Appearently $set and $push has the same effect in this case, unfortunately.